# Как сохранить значения, введенные в поля поиска?

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Допустим, на веб-странице имеется расширенный поиск недвижимости. Пользователь может выбрать чекбоксы или же ввести текст в input поля.

После отправки формы, значения, введенные в поля, сбрасываются.
Какие удобные механизмы для их сохранения существуют?
Слышал, что можно хранить в **localstore** браузера, кто об этом слышал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если отправляешь форму AJAXом, то данные и так сохранятся. Если отправляешь стандартно, то в чем проблема подставить уже полученные сервером переменные в качестве значений полей формы и тем самым сохранить ввод для посетителя? Все равно ведь страницу перегружать, а  пришедшие данные все равно на сервере проверять.
Про LocalStorage вот здесь все понятно написано: http://webknowledge.ru/ispolzovanie-localstorage-dlya-nuzhd-javascript/

Comment: Ajax не использую. Ко всему - форм поиска на сайте - пять. И каждая достаточно сложная. Поэтому писать доп.функционал по сохранению полей - не очень хочется. Может есть более простое решение?

Comment: Ну а куда проще? Получил переменные на сервере, проверил, подставил значения в шаблоны форм соответственно.
С LocalStorage по-моему проблем будет больше, как минимум IE7. Для того, чтобы отправить сразу несколько форм - склеивай их JS. Т.е. создай один общий массив и в нем изменяй элементы при заполнении форм.